# VSFlexgrid licensing issue in VB6

Tags: vb6, licensing, vsflexgrid

I am having a licensing issue with our VideoSoft VSFlexGrid 7.0 in VB6. When I create a new FlexGrid it triggers a message box with a licensing/about message. We have a license but it appears that VB does not quite keep it. Is there a way to get rid of this message?

I currently use a workaround: instead of creating a new FlexGrid I copy an existing one and modify it as needed.

Answer (score 2):

What OS you're using? I have problem with older flexgrid and 64bit Vista - flexgrid installer is 16bit and doesn't run on 64bit Vista; without installer license information cannot be written into registry. I'm using XP for this project.

If flexgrid installer is working in your system, just reinstall it (run in admin privileges!) - that should create developer license in registry. Simply re-registering ocx file doesn't create developer license.

Comment: I use XP here where we create apps. The mainusers of the application use windows 2000 client.

Comment: User OS doesn't matter; at least our flexgrid (version 5 or smtg) is working from Win 95 to Win 7 without problems.
Have you tried to reinstall it on development PC? 
As always, turn antivirus off, remove software, restart, turn antivirus off, install software - all this using administrative account (for local PC!).

Answer (score 1):

You could try to manually re-register the OCX component. In a command line window, run `regsvr32` followed by the name of the .ocx file.

Comment: The file is named: vsflex7l.oca

Comment: .oca are just cached ocx files they get recreated automatically by VB6. They can cause problems if they get out of sync with the ocx. I would delete the oca and re-register the actual ocx

Answer (score 1):

Registering components has nothing to do with licensing, sadly. VB Custom Components (optionally) came with a lic file that was added to the registry by the application installer. Without the correct lic details, you can instantiate a control at runtime, but you cannot at design time.

So, the most likely way to fix this problem is to re-run the original Flex Grid installer.